# how does google analytics generate a unique id?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

is it done through javascript? or is it making a request somewhere with some info and ga sends back a response that is saved in the cookie?

Comment: What unique ID are you referring to exactly?

Comment: _utma, that they use to identify a "unique" visitor

Comment: You might want to consider webmasters.stackexchange.com - the GA stuff is pretty well covered there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It must be done in the JavaScript because there's no additional request made for an ID between the `ga.js` request and the `__utm.gif` beacon being sent. It looks like a combination of a random number and the current date but I can't confirm if that's correct.

One thing I used in a tracking script before was to generate an ID on the server and inject it into the initial JavaScript but I don't see anything like that in `ga.js`. However, `ga.js` is quite hard to read so I could be missing something.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're asking, but an ID, Google Analytics or not, is generated on the server.

From a security perspective, the general rule of thumb about Client-Server applications is that you should never trust the user. Same in this case.
Logically, it doesn't make sense to generate some ID and then bind with it on the server.